# Which large marine animals could live in an ocean 60 m deep?

Tags: science-based, environment, fauna, ecology, ocean

The setting I'm currently working on, has a sea that is large in area, but even the deep ocean, far from land, is only sixty meters deep. (It's a Banks Orbital, but I don't think that matters in and of itself; it seems to me that a planet with similar depth of water, would produce similar results.)

The ocean has been stocked with terrestrial organisms – at least the ones that can survive there.

There will be many that cannot. Presumably most of the species that live in the abyssal depths on Earth, will find a suitable environment simply does not exist in this world; that is to be expected, though not very noticeable to anyone except marine biologists.

The gaps that will be noticeable to the characters, and mentioned in the narrative, will be the charismatic megafauna. I'm thinking in particular of sperm whales, which dive more than a kilometer deep in search of food. According to a documentary I watched a while ago, this seems to be the way they normally make a living; their measured rate of catching food was much higher in deep water than shallow. Presumably this world won't have any sperm whales.

Is there anything else that shares that characteristic? There are many species that *can* dive to great depth, but are there any other household-name species that cannot survive without doing so?

Comment: -1 for lack of research. [There aren't that many "megafauna" creatures in our oceans](https://www.siyachts.com/The-75-Largest-Underwater-Species) and you're not asking a real-world question to help solve a woldbuilding problem. You're just asking for free research. The top 13 critters on that list seem to be the minimum list of megafauna. Might take you an hour to do the research.

Comment: @JBH I'm afraid your comment demonstrates lack of actually thinking about the requirements. You're thinking it would be easy to look up the diving depths of individual species. Sure, but that's not what's in question here. The question is which species have some *need* for greater depth, versus which ones may occasionally dive deep, but can do without. That's a lot less well-documented. In fact, I wouldn't be confident about it for sperm whales, had I not accidentally stumbled across that documentary.

Comment: @AngryMuppet Not necessarily. There might be a singular answer, perhaps some unifying factor determining which species would survive and which would not, that neither of us knows about.

Comment: I'm afraid your comment demonstrates a lack of actually thinking about what I said. *Every animal that dives deeply has a need for doing so - or it wouldn't do it.* Nature takes the path of least resistance. There's *always* a reason why a creature does what it does. So, sorry, but my down vote remains.

Comment: @rwallace We judge questions based on what they ask for, not how a question could be answered. Your ask is for an open ended list, so regardless of whether it's possible to construct a singular answer, the form of the question is not permitted on this site. You can read more about this in the [help]

Comment: Isn't your title question the opposite of the one in body? I understand you want megafishies, but in the body you ask if there are *others that share  the characteristics of sperm whales*. Sperm whales which, uh... You have excluded from your world x).

Comment: The answer to this question would require someone to map out a food web, and that could be done in an infinite number of ways. You have to ask the question of why grazers, plants, and predators would hang out in those zones, and then ask, given those positive aspects, why they wouldn't migrate to shallower or deeper zones.

Answer (score 2):

No mammals are tied to deep diving, it's just a source of food not a biological necessity.

No marine animals that currently live 60 metres and up would have an issue either. It's just availability of food that matters. So anything from whale sharks to whales would be fine if they have something to eat.

Answer (score 2):

Bottlenose dolphins can live in as shallow as 2 meters.

Blacktip, Sandbar and many other smaller sharks hang in water shallow enough for someone to stand on the bottom.

Technically, whales can live in shallower water since they need to breathe, but it depends on the whale’s size. Obviously blue whales can’t survive here, because they are longer than the water is deep, and it would be like a human living in an air vent.

Any whales smaller than blues by 40 to 50 feet and smaller should be fine- to an extent. The smaller the whale, the happier it’ll be, as whales need to dive to get rid of extra nitrogen bubbles, which if left ignored results in decompression sickness.

Obviously, your typical deep sea animals can’t live here. Your theoretical ocean barely consists of a quarter of the existing sunlight zone, which is the first layer of the ocean. All animals in the aphotic zone cannot survive here.

Of course, all this is if our world’s sea life was thrown into yours, and left two weeks or sum to accumulate. If you put creatures in there and waited for, say, 10 million years, animals that otherwise wouldn’t fare well may have evolved to match the environment.

My source: ten million gazillion google searches, and I double searched some info to check the credibility

Hope this helps! ^^